# Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction $R(e^{-2 \pi \sqrt 5})$

Tags: special-functions, continued-fractions

Let  $$R(q) = \cfrac{q^{1/5}}{1 + \cfrac{q}{1 + \cfrac{q^{2}}{1 + \cfrac{q^{3}}{1 + \cdots}}}}$$

It is easy to evaluate $R(e^{-2 \pi/ \sqrt 5})$ using the Dedekind eta function identity $\eta(-\frac{1}{z})=\sqrt{-iz}\eta(z)$

and  one of the most fundamental properties of $R(q)$ $$\frac{1}{R(q)}-1-R(q)=\frac{f(-q^\frac{1}{5})}{q^\frac{1}{5}f(-q^5)}=\frac{\eta(\tau/5)}{\eta(5\tau)}$$
Where $q=e^{2 \pi i \tau}$ and $f(q)$ is the theta function (Ramanujan's notation). then
$$R(e^{-2 \pi/ \sqrt 5})=\sqrt[5]{\sqrt{1+\beta^{10}}-\beta^5}$$
Where $$\beta=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2 } $$ is the golden ratio.

If $\alpha_1 , \alpha_2>0$ and $\alpha_1 \alpha_2=\pi^2$ then
$$\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}+R(e^{-2 \alpha_1})\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}+R(e^{-2 \alpha_2})\bigg)=\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

using this identity, I evaluate  $R(e^{-2 \pi \sqrt 5})$ Since I already know the value of the $R(e^{- 2 \pi/ \sqrt5})$.

$$\color{blue} {R(e^{-2 \pi \sqrt 5})=  \frac{\beta+2}{\beta+\sqrt[5]{\sqrt{1+\beta^{10}}-\beta^5}}-\beta}.$$

There is another way to evaluate $R(e^{-2 \pi \sqrt 5})$.

$R(e^{-2 \pi \sqrt 5})=\sqrt{(\frac{A+1}{2})+1}-\frac{A+1}{2}$

where $A$ satisfies the quadratic equation
$$\frac{A}{\sqrt{5}V}-\frac{\sqrt{5}V}{A}=\bigg(V-V^{-1}\bigg)^2 \bigg(\frac{V-V^{-1}}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{V-V^{-1}}\bigg)$$
and

$$V=\frac{G_{125}}{G_5}$$

where $G_n=2^{-1/4}e^{\pi \sqrt{n}/24} \chi(e^{- \pi \sqrt{n}})$ is the Ramanujan's class invariant(algebraic). $\chi(q)$ is the Ramanujan's fuction defined by  $\chi(-q)=(q;q)_\infty$, Where $(a;q)_n$ is a q-pochhammer symbol.

There are my questions:

$1.$ How to calculate class invariant $G_{125}$ to evaluate $R(e^{-2 \pi \sqrt 5})$?

$2.$ Does there exist another way to evaluate $R(e^{-2 \pi \sqrt 5})$ without using $R(e^{-2 \pi / \sqrt 5})$ and class invariants?